# Powershell - sort loglines by date

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and will need some help regarding greping and sorting. I've a lot of logfiles containing logs in the following format:

`2016-04-29T14:10:15,308000+0100; NOTICE  ; Unknown HostId bla bla bla`

I already know how to filter specific loglines via `dir -r | select-string "bla" | ....`. But now I want to order the found loglines based on the included timestamp. Any hints?

Comment: `Get-Help -full Sort-Object` will help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Sort-Object` to sort the lines by the timestamp.

To get it sorted properly, you'll need to parse the timestamp first though. Simply casting to the `[datetime]` type won't work because of the picoseconds in the timestamp, but we can use [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$LogLines = Get-Content .\logfile.log
$LogLines | Sort-Object { 
    # Grab the timestamp, throw the rest away
    $timestamp,$null = $_ -split ';',2
    # Parse the timestamp, Sort-Object will use the emitted DateTime to sort
    [datetime]::ParseExact($timestamp,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss,ffffffK',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) 
}
```

Comment: Is the timestamp extraction/conversion really needed? The ISO format is string sortable.